# MongoDB bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4 and MongoDB 2.6.6.

I'm writing a bash script and I'm using the following command:

```
mongo cc --eval "printjson(db.cc_data.count())"
```

to get the count of the collection `cc_data`. I would like to save the count returned in a variable, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the output of the shell to a variable. You just need to ensure you suppress the output from the `mongo` shell during the connection process using `--quiet`.

```
let count=`mongo cc --eval "printjson(db.cc_data.count());" --quiet`
```

You can test the value by running:

```
echo $count
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use the following syntax

```
var=$( mongo cc --eval "printjson(db.cc_data.count())" --quiet )
```